# Method that takes a list as input parameter where each item is a different generic type

Tags: c#

NOTE: Please help me format this question better before locking -- I may not be savvy enough to formulate this up to StackOverflow standards. I will edit post as necessary to clarify.

How can I create a method that receives a list, where each item in the list is of a different generic type? I've tried many permutations and I cannot seem to find a way that works. I'm using OpenXml SDK to create Spreadsheets to open in Excel. The idea is to create a single document that accepts as configuration multiple sheets with different row data of type T. My api looks something like this:

```
OpenXmlHelpers.Spreadsheet.CreateDocument(new ArrayList{
    new SheetConfig<Foo> { Name = "Foo sheet", RowData = ..., Columns = ...},
    new SheetConfig<Bar> { Name = "Bar sheet", RowData = ..., Columns = ...},
});
```

where `Foo` and `Bar` are whichever models I want to output as row data on each sheet of the Excel document. And `SheetConfig` is like:

```
public class SheetConfig<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Name of the sheet (shown in the tab)
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Objects to display in the sheet
    /// </summary>
    public IList<T> RowData { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Field names to extract from the RowData and use as header names
    /// </summary>
    public List<ColumnConfig> Columns { get; set; }
}
```

and `ColumnConfig` is like:

```
public class ColumnConfig
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Header text
    /// </summary>
    public string Title { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Object property to use under header
    /// </summary>
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
}
```

So far my `Spreadsheet` class looks like:

```
public class Spreadsheet
{
    public static void CreateDocument(IEnumerable<SheetConfig<T>> configs)
    {
        using (OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocument.Create("file.path.here", OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
        {
            // OpenXml stuff...
            OpenXml.Sheets sheets = new OpenXml.Sheets();

            foreach (var s in configs)
            {
                sheets.AppendChild(CreateSheet(s));
            }
        }
    }

    private static OpenXml.Sheet CreateSheet<T>(SheetConfig<T> config)
    {
        // OpenXML stuff...
        return new OpenXml.Sheet { Name = config.Name };
    }
}
```

First issue is that it complains about `CreateDocument` not being like `CreateDocument<T>` and I supposed input of `IEnumerable<SheetConfig<T>>` isn't completely correct because the list isn't of all the same type `T` but any number of types, like `Foo` and `Bar`.

Comment: Do you have control over the model classes (e.g., `Foo`, `Bar`)? Can you ensure they all have the same base class (e.g., `ModelBase`)?

Comment: @ThomasBarnekow I do have control, but the idea is to just generically be able to export any list of objects -- one sheet per type. In my particular case these are Entity models from database that a user wants to export. The ColumnConfig lets the spreadsheet builder know which properties we want to export into columns, and the Excel cell datatype is set based on the data type of the property

Comment: Have a look at whether my answer below and tell me whether that goes in the right direction for your context. You might not need the `Dictionary` approach in case you have Entity models (using EntityFramework?).

Comment: there is no COVARIANCE in C#.  Short answer is NO you cannot do what you want straight forward.   You could create a List<object> or object[].   The other possibility is using interfaces if your models implement a common interface you can create for example a List<MyInterface> or MyInterface[].    The last option is a bite more complex but you wont need to use base classes or interfaces...that is using REFLECTION which can be complicated but it can be driven by strings of "metadata" like the FieldName in your ColumnConfig, You might also need the "TypeName" and other data.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to make sure you have a common base class for all of your model classes, which I have called `ModelBase` in the sample code below. This is much like the `OpenXmlElement` class in the Open XML SDK, which is the base class of all strongly typed classes provided by the SDK.

```cs
    public class ModelBase
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        public object GetValue(string fieldName)
        {
            return _values.TryGetValue(fieldName, out object value) ? value : null;
        }

        public void SetValue(string fieldName, object value)
        {
            _values[fieldName] = value;
        }
    }

    public class Foo : ModelBase
    {
        public string First
        {
            get => (string) GetValue(nameof(First));
            set => SetValue(nameof(First), value);
        }

        public int Second
        {
            get => (int) GetValue(nameof(Second));
            set => SetValue(nameof(Second), value);
        }
    }

    public class Bar : ModelBase
    {
        public string One
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(nameof(One));
            set => SetValue(nameof(One), value);
        }

        public DateTime Two
        {
            get => (DateTime) GetValue(nameof(Two));
            set => SetValue(nameof(Two), value);
        }
    }
```

The above sample code defines two model classes, `Foo` and `Bar`, both of which derive from `ModelBase`. The latter also provides "generic" getter and setter methods that are backed by a `Dictionary<string, object>`, which can be used to store the values by field name.

Based on the code above, you would amend your `SheetConfig<T>` as shown below, i.e., by adding the constraint `where T : ModelBase`.

```cs
    public class SheetConfig<T> where T : ModelBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Name of the sheet (shown in the tab)
        /// </summary>
        public string Name { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Objects to display in the sheet
        /// </summary>
        public IList<T> RowData { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Field names to extract from the RowData and use as header names
        /// </summary>
        public List<ColumnConfig> Columns { get; set; }
    }

    public class ColumnConfig
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Header text
        /// </summary>
        public string Title { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Object property to use under header
        /// </summary>
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
    }
```

Lastly, your code did not compile because you should have written `CreateDocument<T>(...)` instead of just `CreateDocument(...)`. However, the type parameter is no longer necessary, because you can now use `IEnumerable<SheetConfig<ModelBase>> configs` as the formal parameter. Overall, the `Spreadsheet` class can be changed as follows:

```
    public class Spreadsheet
    {
        public static void CreateDocument(IEnumerable<SheetConfig<ModelBase>> configs)
        {
            using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create("file.path.here", SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                // OpenXml stuff...
                var sheets = new Sheets();

                foreach (SheetConfig<ModelBase> s in configs)
                {
                    sheets.AppendChild(CreateSheet(s));
                }
            }
        }

        private static Sheet CreateSheet(SheetConfig<ModelBase> config)
        {
            // OpenXML stuff...
            return new Sheet { Name = config.Name };
        }
    }
```

Comment: This seems like it would work but I should probably assume I don't have control over the model classes since this will eventually be a generic library that all my internal customers will use. Sorry if I led you astray by saying I have control over them.

Comment: Also, considering `CreateDocument` vs `CreateDocument<T>`, really the Document can hold any number of sheets with any number of types, so I probably don't even want it to be typed. I figured the `SheetConfig` needs to be `SheetConfig<T>` because my property `RowData` is `IList` which requires a type. So maybe I just use `SheetConfig` and `RowData` is `IList<object>` ?

Comment: I'd say it all depends on how you want to process your models. If you don't have to make any assumption about the model and just use reflection, for example, to get hold of the properties to render in the Excel sheet, you can as well go with `object`. Should you want a certain minimum functionality in the base model, you would have to make sure they all derive from the same base class or implement some interface.

Comment: I don't want to make any assumptions about the model. It's pretty much a one-to-one mapping. Maybe I'm missing something fundamental: "Cannot implicitly convert type List<Foo> to IList<object>"

Comment: If you don't want to make any assumptions about the models, you would simply replace all occurrences of `ModelBase` in my sample code with `object` and get rid of the generic type parameter `T` in `SheetConfig<T>`. `IList<T> RowData` then becomes `IList<object> RowData`. Finally, you would use reflection, much like the EntityFramework itself, to get the models' property values.

Comment: Did that answer your question or help you find the solution or both?